# Are there any public holidays in the 24th century?

Tags: star-trek

I've noticed that there seems to be a noticeable absence of 'public holidays' in the Star Trek universe.  I imagine that the fact that we're normally with Starfleet personnel would impact this, but do we have any evidence to support that public holidays (on Earth specifically) still exist in the 24th century?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple search on Memory-Alpha results in a [small list of holidays](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holidays_and_festivals). Most are personal or regional, which can be expected, but at least 2 seemed to be somewhat public: [First Contact Day](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/First_Contact_Day) (Earth) and [Federation Day](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation_Day) (all of the Federation?).

Comment: Not to forget the *Captain Picard Day*! How could you skip that awesome day?

Comment: That's a private/regional holiday :|

Comment: @Mario - and Commander Riker Day. I think we can assume that Picard made that happen.

Comment: First Contact Day was invented by Neelix.

Answer (score 2):

Of course they exist, but as the crew ( ship and camera ) are not working that day we do not see them. Makes for a rather dull episode.

Comment: I dunno, there have been a couple parties and such we have seen in the first scene that have been interrupted by the emergency of the week.  Generations for example started on a promotion ceremony/party and got interrupted.  That probably was supposed to have been a slow day for the crew.

Comment: Ceremonies and parties would not be "public holidays". And as the series centers around a quasi-military vessel the entire crew never gets the whole day off unless it's docked or otherwise out of service.

Comment: Mental note; plan invasion of federation on Federation day